# Google maps draw distance traveled polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I would like to draw a 'distance traveled' polyline over a preset route using V3 of the google maps API.

The polyline would need to run through multiple waypoints/legs.

I am currently using the DirectionsService to draw the complete route.

I am also using epolys.js to get the marker position for the distance traveled.

I am copying the complete route into a new polyline, but I would only like to copy the route up to the marker position.

Demo link: http://codepen.io/1983ron/pen/wKMVQr

And here's where I'm currently at with the JS

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var gmarkers = [];
var METERS_TO_MILES = 0.000621371192;
var walked = (Math.round(670 * 1609.344));

//ICON
var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://www.ronnieatkinson.co.uk/clients/wc2015/maps/01/mapIcons/marker_red.png',       //MARKER URL
    new google.maps.Size(20, 34),   //MARKER SIZE (WxH)
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),     //MARKER ORIGIN
    new google.maps.Point(9, 34)    //MARKER ANCHOR
);

//SHADOW
var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',  //SHADOW URL
    new google.maps.Size(37, 34),                   //SHADOW SIZE (WxH)
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),                     //SHADOW ORIGIN
    new google.maps.Point(9, 34)                    //SHADOW ANCHOR
);

//INFO WINDOW
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
});

//CREATE MARKER
function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
    var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        shadow: iconShadow,
        icon: iconImage,
        title: label,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
    });

    marker.myname = label;
    gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    return marker;
}

function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.555967, -0.279736);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    var rendererOptions = {
        map: map,
        suppressMarkers: true,
    };

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    //Edinburgh to Eden Project
    var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(58.981386, -2.973751); //Orkney Rugby Football Club
    var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.881517, -4.342057); //Scotstoun Stadium
    var point3 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.998080, -7.319812); //Guildhall St
    var point4 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.563716, -5.942729); //Belfast Harlequins RFC
    var point5 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.271057, -9.054253); //Hotel Spanish Arch
    var point6 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.674222, -8.642515); //Thomond Park
    var point7 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.291755, -3.713769); //Colwyn Leisure Centre
    var point8 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.748180, -3.618567); //Glynneath Rugby Football Club

    var wps = [
        { location: point1 },
        { location: point2 },
        { location: point3 },
        { location: point4 },
        { location: point5 },
        { location: point6 },
        { location: point7 },
        { location: point8 }
    ];

    //START
    var org = new google.maps.LatLng (55.945315, -3.205309); //EDINBURGH 

    //FINISH
    var dest = new google.maps.LatLng (50.360130, -4.744717); //EDEN PROJECT

    var request = {
        origin: org,
        destination: dest,
        waypoints: wps,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
        //unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
    };

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            //SHOW ROUTE
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            //COPY POLY FROM DIRECTION SERVICE
            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeWeight: 3
            });

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
            for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
                var steps = legs[i].steps;
                for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
                    var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                    for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
                        polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                        bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                    }
                }
            }

            polyline.setMap(map);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

            //alert(walked);

            //ADD MARKER TO NEW POLYLINE AT 'X' DISTANCE
            createMarker(polyline.GetPointAtDistance(walked), "You are here", (Math.round( walked * METERS_TO_MILES * 10 ) / 10)+' miles');

            //GET THE TOTAL DISTANCE
            var distance= 0;
            //var METERS_TO_MILES = 0.000621371192;
            for(i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++){
                //FOR EACH LEG GET THE DISTANCE AND ADD IT TO THE TOTAL
                distance += parseFloat(response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value);
            }
            //alert((Math.round( distance * METERS_TO_MILES * 10 ) / 10)+' miles');
            //alert(distance); //METERS

        } else if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED){
            alert ('Max waypoints exceeded');
        } else {
            alert ('failed to get directions');
        }
    });
};window.onload = function() { initialize(); };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: `MarkerImage` was deprecated a long time ago and shadows are no longer supported for markers.

Comment: @geocodezip Thankyou, i'll update/remove these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the length of the line as you create it.  Once it becomes greater than or equal to the distance "walked", stop adding points to it.

```
var lengthMeters = 0;
var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
    var steps = legs[i].steps;
    for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
        var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
        for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
            if (lengthMeters <= walked) { 
                // if polyline is less than distance "walked", keep adding to it
                polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                if (polyline.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
                   var lastPt = polyline.getPath().getLength() - 1;
                   lengthMeters += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(polyline.getPath().getAt(lastPt - 1), polyline.getPath().getAt(lastPt));
                }
            }
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
         }
    }
}
polyline.setMap(map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2s8xu9s0/11/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;
var gmarkers = [];
var METERS_TO_MILES = 0.000621371192;
var walked = (Math.round(670 * 1609.344));

//ICON
var iconImage = {

  url: 'http://www.ronnieatkinson.co.uk/clients/wc2015/maps/01/mapIcons/marker_red.png', //MARKER URL
  size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34), //MARKER SIZE (WxH)
  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), //MARKER ORIGIN
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(9, 34) //MARKER ANCHOR
};

//INFO WINDOW
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
});

//CREATE MARKER
function createMarker(latlng, label, html) {
  var contentString = '<b>' + label + '</b><br>' + html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    icon: iconImage,
    title: label,
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat() * -100000) << 5
  });

  marker.myname = label;
  gmarkers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  return marker;
}

function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.555967, -0.279736);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

  var rendererOptions = {
    map: map,
    suppressMarkers: true,
  };

  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

  //Edinburgh to Eden Project
  var point1 = new google.maps.LatLng(58.981386, -2.973751); //Orkney Rugby Football Club
  var point2 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.881517, -4.342057); //Scotstoun Stadium
  var point3 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.998080, -7.319812); //Guildhall St
  var point4 = new google.maps.LatLng(54.563716, -5.942729); //Belfast Harlequins RFC
  var point5 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.271057, -9.054253); //Hotel Spanish Arch
  var point6 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.674222, -8.642515); //Thomond Park
  var point7 = new google.maps.LatLng(53.291755, -3.713769); //Colwyn Leisure Centre
  var point8 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.748180, -3.618567); //Glynneath Rugby Football Club

  var wps = [{
    location: point1
  }, {
    location: point2
  }, {
    location: point3
  }, {
    location: point4
  }, {
    location: point5
  }, {
    location: point6
  }, {
    location: point7
  }, {
    location: point8
  }];

  //START
  var org = new google.maps.LatLng(55.945315, -3.205309); //EDINBURGH 

  //FINISH
  var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(50.360130, -4.744717); //EDEN PROJECT

  var request = {
    origin: org,
    destination: dest,
    waypoints: wps,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
    //unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
  };

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      //SHOW ROUTE
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

      //COPY POLY FROM DIRECTION SERVICE
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [],
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeWeight: 3
      });

      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var lengthMeters = 0;
      var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
      for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
        var steps = legs[i].steps;
        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
          var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
          for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {

            if (lengthMeters <= walked) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              if (polyline.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
                var lastPt = polyline.getPath().getLength() - 1;
                lengthMeters += google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(polyline.getPath().getAt(lastPt - 1), polyline.getPath().getAt(lastPt));
              }
            }
            bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);

          }
        }
      }

      polyline.setMap(map);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);

      //alert(walked);

      //ADD MARKER TO NEW POLYLINE AT 'X' DISTANCE
      createMarker(polyline.GetPointAtDistance(walked), "You are here", (Math.round(walked * METERS_TO_MILES * 10) / 10) + ' miles');

      //GET THE TOTAL DISTANCE
      var distance = 0;
      //var METERS_TO_MILES = 0.000621371192;
      for (i = 0; i < response.routes[0].legs.length; i++) {
        //FOR EACH LEG GET THE DISTANCE AND ADD IT TO THE TOTAL
        distance += parseFloat(response.routes[0].legs[i].distance.value);
      }
      //alert((Math.round( distance * METERS_TO_MILES * 10 ) / 10)+' miles');
      //alert(distance); //METERS

    } else if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED) {
      alert('Max waypoints exceeded');
    } else {
      alert('failed to get directions');
    }
  });
};
window.onload = function() {
  initialize();
};

/*********************************************************************\
*                                                                     *
* epolys.js                                          by Mike Williams *
* updated to API v3                                  by Larry Ross    *
*                                                                     *
* A Google Maps API Extension                                         *
*                                                                     *
* Adds various Methods to google.maps.Polygon and google.maps.Polyline *
*                                                                     *
* .Contains(latlng) returns true is the poly contains the specified   *
*                   GLatLng                                           *
*                                                                     *
* .Area()           returns the approximate area of a poly that is    *
*                   not self-intersecting                             *
*                                                                     *
* .Distance()       returns the length of the poly path               *
*                                                                     *
* .Bounds()         returns a GLatLngBounds that bounds the poly      *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointAtDistance() returns a GLatLng at the specified distance   *
*                   along the path.                                   *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Reurns null if the path is shorter than that      *
*                                                                     *
* .GetPointsAtDistance() returns an array of GLatLngs at the          *
*                   specified interval along the path.                *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                                                                     *
* .GetIndexAtDistance() returns the vertex number at the specified    *
*                   distance along the path.                          *
*                   The distance is specified in metres               *
*                   Returns null if the path is shorter than that      *
*                                                                     *
* .Bearing(v1?,v2?) returns the bearing between two vertices          *
*                   if v1 is null, returns bearing from first to last *
*                   if v2 is null, returns bearing from v1 to next    *
*                                                                     *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
*   This Javascript is provided by Mike Williams                      *
*   Blackpool Community Church Javascript Team                        *
*   http://www.blackpoolchurch.org/                                   *
*   http://econym.org.uk/gmap/                                        *
*                                                                     *
*   This work is licenced under a Creative Commons Licence            *
*   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/                    *
*                                                                     *
***********************************************************************
*                                                                     *
* Version 1.1       6-Jun-2007                                        *
* Version 1.2       1-Jul-2007 - fix: Bounds was omitting vertex zero *
*                                add: Bearing                         *
* Version 1.3       28-Nov-2008  add: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 1.4       12-Jan-2009  fix: GetPointsAtDistance()           *
* Version 3.0       11-Aug-2010  update to v3                         *
*                                                                     *
\*********************************************************************/

// === first support methods that don't (yet) exist in v3
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(newLatLng) {
  var EarthRadiusMeters = 6378137.0; // meters
  var lat1 = this.lat();
  var lon1 = this.lng();
  var lat2 = newLatLng.lat();
  var lon2 = newLatLng.lng();
  var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = EarthRadiusMeters * c;
  return d;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.latRadians = function() {
  return this.lat() * Math.PI / 180;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lngRadians = function() {
  return this.lng() * Math.PI / 180;
}

// === A method which returns the length of a path in metres ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance = function() {
  var dist = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i < this.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
  }
  return dist;
}

// === A method which returns a GLatLng of a point a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  if (this.getPath().getLength() < 2) return null;
  var dist = 0;
  var olddist = 0;
  for (var i = 1;
    (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 2);
  var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
  var m = (metres - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
  return new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m);
}

// === A method which returns an array of GLatLngs of points a given interval along the path ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = function(metres) {
  var next = metres;
  var points = [];
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres <= 0) return points;
  var dist = 0;
  var olddist = 0;
  for (var i = 1;
    (i < this.getPath().getLength()); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
    while (dist > next) {
      var p1 = this.getPath().getAt(i - 1);
      var p2 = this.getPath().getAt(i);
      var m = (next - olddist) / (dist - olddist);
      points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(p1.lat() + (p2.lat() - p1.lat()) * m, p1.lng() + (p2.lng() - p1.lng()) * m));
      next += metres;
    }
  }
  return points;
}

// === A method which returns the Vertex number at a given distance along the path ===
// === Returns null if the path is shorter than the specified distance ===
google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance = function(metres) {
  // some awkward special cases
  if (metres == 0) return this.getPath().getAt(0);
  if (metres < 0) return null;
  var dist = 0;
  var olddist = 0;
  for (var i = 1;
    (i < this.getPath().getLength() && dist < metres); i++) {
    olddist = dist;
    dist += this.getPath().getAt(i).distanceFrom(this.getPath().getAt(i - 1));
  }
  if (dist < metres) {
    return null;
  }
  return i;
}

// === Copy all the above functions to GPolyline ===
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.Distance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.Distance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetPointsAtDistance;
google.maps.Polyline.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.GetIndexAtDistance;
```

```css
html,
body,
#map,
#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```